# How to add the custom data after username?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook

When I use [Facebook Graph API](https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed) to create the post at the own wall, the post always contains my username at the very first row. Is it possible to add my custom data after the username in the same row?

I want to have something like this:

```html
<Username> recommends a <link>product</link> at the something.
```

What should I use for it: graph api, open graph or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is very possible.  Please research into Open Graph. See: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/opengraph/

and for a good walk-thru: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/opengraph/tutorial/